# Difficulties converting to Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3, xcode8, ios10

After converting from Swift 2 to Swift 3 (even after converting edit-> convert -> to current swift syntax) I am getting lots of errors.   Especially:

[image: this]

I am shown total 90 errors for my project which was working fine in Swift 2 before i downloaded this beta Xcode 8.0 and converted to Swift 3

Is this a conversion mistake I am making?

Comment: @EricD i want to know is the method to convert code i use
edit-> convert -> to current swift syntax 
 is correct or not. If there is a better method then just to help me with that. thats all i asked for.

Comment: @niravdesai21 Yes this is the right command. This command does most of the work, but it's up to you to do the rest. Xcode is just an IDE, not a magical thing. :) Read the Swift 3 docs if you're lost with the changes.

Comment: Also, it is possible that the conversion didn't work right. Try converting it again, even if it gives you a warning that the file was already converted to Swift 3

Comment: I had over a 100 errors when I converted. Come to find about 80% of the errors were resolved when I updated my libraries. In particular I was using Swifty JSON. I uploaded the latest file version and voilà, the rest was manageable stepping through code.

Answer (score 185, accepted):

Most of them are easy fixes, simply by tapping the red button, and having Xcode fix it for you! Others include:

**CGRect**

Swift 2:

```
let frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)
```

Swift 3:

```
let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20)
```

**CGPoint**

Swift 2:

```
let point = CGPointMake(0, 0)
```

Swift 3:

```
let point = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
```

**CGSize**

Swift 2:

```
let size = CGSizeMake(20, 20)
```

Swift 3:

```
let size = CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)
```

**CGRectGetMidX**

Swift 2:

```
CGRectGetMidX(view)
```

Swift 3:

```
view.midX
```

**CGRectGetMidY**

Swift 2:

```
CGRectGetMidY(view)
```

Swift 3:

```
view.midY
```

**UIColor**

Swift 2:

```
let color = UIColor.redColor()
```

Swift 3:

```
let color = UIColor.red
```

**"NS"**

Swift 2:

```
NSTimer
NSData
NSError
```

Swift 3:

```
Timer
Data
Error
```

**UserDefaults**

Swift 2:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().//something
```

Swift 3:

```
UserDefaults.standard.//something
```

Comment: This helped me out a lot, while I was working I found one more that was a recurring change **CGRectGetMidX && CGRectGetMidY**
Swift 2:
CGRectGetMidX(object) || CGRectGetMidY(object)

Swift 3:
object.midX  || object.midY

Comment: Thanks @TylerHack I'll include that in my answer. Glad to help!

Comment: i have hundreds of CGRectMake etc, how is that easy to change? maybe by regexp, but even so quite dangerous

Comment: @nights try converting it again. I believe the default conversion will fix it.

Comment: tried a hundred times and it will not convert anything :[  now making changes manually...counting days

Comment: Also size, point and rect with 0 as the values, it can be done like this.

Comment: let size = CGSize.zero,
let point = CGPoint.zero,
let rect = CGRect.zero

Answer (score 12):

And always remember to use the helpful "Fix all in Scope" function which can be found at Editor -> Fix all in Scope

Answer (score 1):

I was converting a project and Xcode was not helping me with any fixes so I resorted to a couple of regex search-and-replaces:-

```
CGPointMake\((.*),[ ]*([^\)]+)\)
CGPoint(x:$1, y:$2)

CGSizeMake\((.*),[ ]*([^\)]+)\)
CGSize(width:$1, height:$2)
```

Note they are not aware of nested parentheses , but probably good enough for 90% of cases.