# Conversion to Swift 3 with Xcode 8

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8

To use Xcode 8 with a Swift project we have to convert it to the new Swift 3 syntax.

I've a project with several cocoapods. First, I have installed all the new versions of these pods from the respective sources, so they are already converted to the Swift 3.

Then, I used the `Edit -> Convert -> To current Swift syntax choosing Swift 3` for my main target (basically the real app). Everything seemed to be fine, but at the first build I received a lot of errors, even simple ones, fixable with the `CMD+ALT+CTRL+F`, but they increase at every build. I think that this conversion tool is not the best one, or something went wrong..

Can you point me to the right direction?

Screenshot to show you the problems

[image: screenshot errors]

Comment: Can you show some of the errors?

Comment: I am struggle with the same problem - this conversation only works for very small projects. So at the moment i stay in version 7.3.1 - and later on i will rebuild the project from scrap (so copy class for class - try to convert / check syntax) - but this will take at least one full day for a single project.

Comment: And check out this:  Still a lot of "manual" work to convert to the latest syntax. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37946899/converting-to-swift-3-difficulties?rq=1

Comment: If there is any pod in your project than update pods. And clear derived data folder and run again. @Andrea Mario Lufino

Comment: For anything substantial, I have come to expect that kind of work, too. Sometimes, there are several possible changes, e.g. WRT `!`, with automatic solutions not always the preferable ones. Also, there seems to be a mix of diagnoses generated by Xcode's own analyzer and then the swift compiler proper. The preview helps in that is shows what happens if you pick this or that solution (number of follow-up errors/changes), but may require going back and forth. Still, the process seems tedious, sometimes being lifted only by educated guesswork.

Comment: doesnt convert swift files, avoid this page

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know that it is sad, but there is no other solution than changing your code manually. It is the same with constrains which are also different and you have to change them all (if they are wrong) :/ .

Comment: I ran into this same thing.  All of my constraints had to be redone.  Huge pain telling a client that the simple label update they wanted is going to take 4+ hours as I redo the entire layout of their app.

Comment: Of course, XCode gracefully shows you fix option beside the error mark, you could follow that option to get rid of aforementioned troubles

Answer (score 3):

You can goto free services (for big files you must upgrade accont) , 
clear and easy :

[Online Convertor](https://objectivec2swift.com/#/home/converter/)

You can make convertion by converting small block of code . Sometimes line by line .

Other way is to make objectiveC bridge in your swift3 project.

Use (in combination with online convertor) Auto correct from xcode 8.Its very useful (must be careful with auto correct sometimes you will degrade   code ).

***In the basics : Its not bad , you must fix all errors manually .Best way for learn swift 3 . 90% of errors are very easy to fix , just follow logs ...***

Comment: Does this service convert from swift 2.0 -> 3.0 or only form objc -> swift 2/3

Comment: No , but no need for that . If you can download xcode 8.0 ver or >8.0 auto correct will do this job for you .

Comment: That is the theory, IRL not that simple. Take Range for instance. Totally re-engineered in 3.0.

Comment: Here are my trails and tribulations going from swift 2 -> 3 http://stylekit.org/blog/2017/01/12/swift-3-migration/